# In CNN, should we have more layers with less filters or less layers with large number of filters?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification

I am trying to understand the effect of adding more layers vs the effect of increasing the number of filters in the existing layers in a CNN. Consider a CNN with 2 hidden layers and 64 filters each. Consider a second CNN with 4 hidden layers and 32 filters each. The kernel sizes are same in both CNNs. The number of parameters are also same in both cases.

Which one should I expect to perform better? I am thinking in terms of hyperparameter tuning, batch sizes, training time etc.

Answer (score 0):

In CNNs the deeper layers correspond to higher-level features in images. In the first layer, you are going to get low-level features such as edges, lines, etc. So the network uses these layers to create more complex features; using edges to find circles, using circles to find wheels, using wheels to find a car (I skipped a couple of steps but you get the gist).

So to answer your question, you need to consider how complex your problem is. If you are working on something like imagenet, you can expect model with more layers to have the edge. On the other hand, for problems like mnist, you don't need high-level features.